# Adding pulsing animation to CosmosView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I am trying to add a CABasicAnimation to a CosmosView (https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos) star. I have the stars inside a custom UITableViewCell class and I am trying to specifically target the stars. My code so far looks like:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {
    self.selectionStyle = .none

    cosmosRatingView.settings.starSize = 50
    cosmosRatingView.rating = 0

    contentView.addSubview(cosmosRatingView)
    configureRatingPulseAnimation()

    updateConstraints()
}

func configureRatingPulseAnimation() {
    let ratingPulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    ratingPulseAnimation.duration = 30
    ratingPulseAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.0)
    ratingPulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0)
    ratingPulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    ratingPulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    ratingPulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
    self.contentView.layer.add(ratingPulseAnimation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
    cosmosRatingView.layer.add(ratingPulseAnimation, forKey: "animateOpacityRating")

}


override func updateConstraints() {
    if !didSetupConstraints {
        cosmosRatingView.autoAlignAxis(toSuperviewAxis: .vertical)
        cosmosRatingView.autoAlignAxis(toSuperviewAxis: .horizontal)

        didSetupConstraints = true
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

Sadly, this isn't working. Also, when I try to apply the animation to the cell's `contentView.layer` itself it doesn't work either.

Comment: From this code alone it's not clear that you've set the size of the `cosmosRatingView`.  Did you add constraints and/or set the frame?  If so, post more code.

Comment: What method is that code from? ViewDidLoad or something else?

Comment: Just added more code to show what it looks like in my project. @par, I use PureLayout and auto align the axis. Additionally, the CosmosView itself will show perfectly without me specifying a size, but even when I do the problem persists.

Comment: Adding an opacity animation to both a view and its superview at the same time might be problematic (not sure, never tried it). Try this using a `UIView` animation - `cosmosRatingView.alpha = 0 ; UIView.animate(withDuration: 30, options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut, .repeat], animations: { [weak self] in self?.cosmosRatingView.alpha = 1 }, completion: nil)`